# Bash - How to execute a Terminal command without opening the Terminal GUI

Tags: bash, gui, gnome-terminal

I am trying to execute a Terminal command in bash, but I don't want the Terminal GUI  to open.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "java ABC"
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`gnome-terminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) command causes a GUI terminal application to open. Instead of using `gnome-terminal` to run the command, make your script simply run the command:

```
#!/bin/bash
java ABC
```